# How to blend 2 different metahumans seemlessly during animation

Tags: animation, graphic-effects, skeletal-animation, unreal-5, metahuman

I'm new on this site so please let me know if this is the wrong section to post to.

I have an idea for a whole bunch of animations revolving around 2 semi-identical twins that live in the same body. I have 2 separate metahumans in Unreal Engine that are almost identical with the exception of a few details like eyes, hair, etc.

I want to create a transition animation where one metahuman model seemlessly "blends into" another for scenes where one sister takes over from the other sister. Up until this point, I've used clever camera cuts to swap models. But I want to show the process of the swapping without any cuts. She closes her eyes, small facial features change, and she opens her eyes revealing a completely different color.

Is this even possible? I'm willing to compromise and make the metahumans identical with exception to the eyes, but I'd rather not. Where can I look to start approaching such a thing?

Could this be done using texture swaps instead? I wouldn't need to change models, but I can simply swap the textures on the metahumans through script.

Comment: Look into shape keys and or texture blending. Pure textures can be swapped by blending from one texture to the other. Physical differences can be stored in shape keys and animated.